# Create a 3D Slideshow with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, slideshow, carousel

I'm looking to create a 3D Slideshow or carousel through jQuery, CSS, and HTML.
Something like this is what i want to have 
http://www.masterslider.com/features/templates/3d-flow-carousel/

It would be nice if you can include the reflection on the images as well. I only plan to put 3-5 into the carousel.

Here is the code

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x315" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Caption Text</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x315" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Caption Text</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x315" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Caption Text</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>
</div> <!-- Carousel -->
```

Css

```
.carousel {
  position: relative;
}
.carousel-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.carousel-inner > .item {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
  -webkit-transition: .6s ease-in-out left;
       -o-transition: .6s ease-in-out left;
          transition: .6s ease-in-out left;
}
.carousel-inner > .item > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
  line-height: 1;
}
@media all and (transform-3d), (-webkit-transform-3d) {
  .carousel-inner > .item {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .6s ease-in-out;
         -o-transition:      -o-transform .6s ease-in-out;
            transition:         transform .6s ease-in-out;

    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
            backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
            perspective: 1000;
  }
  .carousel-inner > .item.next,
  .carousel-inner > .item.active.right {
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  }
  .carousel-inner > .item.prev,
  .carousel-inner > .item.active.left {
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  }
  .carousel-inner > .item.next.left,
  .carousel-inner > .item.prev.right,
  .carousel-inner > .item.active {
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}
.carousel-inner > .active,
.carousel-inner > .next,
.carousel-inner > .prev {
  display: block;
}
.carousel-inner > .active {
  left: 0;
}
.carousel-inner > .next,
.carousel-inner > .prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.carousel-inner > .next {
  left: 100%;
}
.carousel-inner > .prev {
  left: -100%;
}
.carousel-inner > .next.left,
.carousel-inner > .prev.right {
  left: 0;
}
.carousel-inner > .active.left {
  left: -100%;
}
.carousel-inner > .active.right {
  left: 100%;
}
.carousel-control {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 15%;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
  opacity: .5;
}
.carousel-control.left {
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .0001) 100%);
  background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .0001) 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, .0001)));
  background-image:         linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .0001) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#80000000', endColorstr='#00000000', GradientType=1);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
.carousel-control.right {
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, .0001) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 100%);
  background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, .0001) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, .0001)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)));
  background-image:         linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, .0001) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#80000000', GradientType=1);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
.carousel-control:hover,
.carousel-control:focus {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  filter: alpha(opacity=90);
  outline: 0;
  opacity: .9;
}
.carousel-control .icon-prev,
.carousel-control .icon-next,
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left,
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 5;
  display: inline-block;
}
.carousel-control .icon-prev,
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left {
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -10px;
}
.carousel-control .icon-next,
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right {
  right: 50%;
  margin-right: -10px;
}
.carousel-control .icon-prev,
.carousel-control .icon-next {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  font-family: serif;
  line-height: 1;
}
.carousel-control .icon-prev:before {
  content: '\2039';
}
.carousel-control .icon-next:before {
  content: '\203a';
}
.carousel-indicators {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 15;
  width: 60%;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-left: -30%;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
}
.carousel-indicators li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 1px;
  text-indent: -999px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #000 \9;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.carousel-indicators .active {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.carousel-caption {
  position: absolute;
  right: 15%;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 15%;
  z-index: 10;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
}
.carousel-caption .btn {
  text-shadow: none;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left,
  .carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right,
  .carousel-control .icon-prev,
  .carousel-control .icon-next {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  .carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left,
  .carousel-control .icon-prev {
    margin-left: -15px;
  }
  .carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right,
  .carousel-control .icon-next {
    margin-right: -15px;
  }
  .carousel-caption {
    right: 20%;
    left: 20%;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
  }
  .carousel-indicators {
    bottom: 20px;
  }
}
```

Script

```
+function ($) {
  'use strict';

  // CAROUSEL CLASS DEFINITION
  // =========================

  var Carousel = function (element, options) {
    this.$element    = $(element)
    this.$indicators = this.$element.find('.carousel-indicators')
    this.options     = options
    this.paused      = null
    this.sliding     = null
    this.interval    = null
    this.$active     = null
    this.$items      = null

    this.options.keyboard && this.$element.on('keydown.bs.carousel', $.proxy(this.keydown, this))

    this.options.pause == 'hover' && !('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement) && this.$element
      .on('mouseenter.bs.carousel', $.proxy(this.pause, this))
      .on('mouseleave.bs.carousel', $.proxy(this.cycle, this))
  }

  Carousel.VERSION  = '3.3.4'

  Carousel.TRANSITION_DURATION = 600

  Carousel.DEFAULTS = {
    interval: 5000,
    pause: 'hover',
    wrap: true,
    keyboard: true
  }

  Carousel.prototype.keydown = function (e) {
    if (/input|textarea/i.test(e.target.tagName)) return
    switch (e.which) {
      case 37: this.prev(); break
      case 39: this.next(); break
      default: return
    }

    e.preventDefault()
  }

  Carousel.prototype.cycle = function (e) {
    e || (this.paused = false)

    this.interval && clearInterval(this.interval)

    this.options.interval
      && !this.paused
      && (this.interval = setInterval($.proxy(this.next, this), this.options.interval))

    return this
  }

  Carousel.prototype.getItemIndex = function (item) {
    this.$items = item.parent().children('.item')
    return this.$items.index(item || this.$active)
  }

  Carousel.prototype.getItemForDirection = function (direction, active) {
    var activeIndex = this.getItemIndex(active)
    var willWrap = (direction == 'prev' && activeIndex === 0)
                || (direction == 'next' && activeIndex == (this.$items.length - 1))
    if (willWrap && !this.options.wrap) return active
    var delta = direction == 'prev' ? -1 : 1
    var itemIndex = (activeIndex + delta) % this.$items.length
    return this.$items.eq(itemIndex)
  }

  Carousel.prototype.to = function (pos) {
    var that        = this
    var activeIndex = this.getItemIndex(this.$active = this.$element.find('.item.active'))

    if (pos > (this.$items.length - 1) || pos < 0) return

    if (this.sliding)       return this.$element.one('slid.bs.carousel', function () { that.to(pos) }) // yes, "slid"
    if (activeIndex == pos) return this.pause().cycle()

    return this.slide(pos > activeIndex ? 'next' : 'prev', this.$items.eq(pos))
  }

  Carousel.prototype.pause = function (e) {
    e || (this.paused = true)

    if (this.$element.find('.next, .prev').length && $.support.transition) {
      this.$element.trigger($.support.transition.end)
      this.cycle(true)
    }

    this.interval = clearInterval(this.interval)

    return this
  }

  Carousel.prototype.next = function () {
    if (this.sliding) return
    return this.slide('next')
  }

  Carousel.prototype.prev = function () {
    if (this.sliding) return
    return this.slide('prev')
  }

  Carousel.prototype.slide = function (type, next) {
    var $active   = this.$element.find('.item.active')
    var $next     = next || this.getItemForDirection(type, $active)
    var isCycling = this.interval
    var direction = type == 'next' ? 'left' : 'right'
    var that      = this

    if ($next.hasClass('active')) return (this.sliding = false)

    var relatedTarget = $next[0]
    var slideEvent = $.Event('slide.bs.carousel', {
      relatedTarget: relatedTarget,
      direction: direction
    })
    this.$element.trigger(slideEvent)
    if (slideEvent.isDefaultPrevented()) return

    this.sliding = true

    isCycling && this.pause()

    if (this.$indicators.length) {
      this.$indicators.find('.active').removeClass('active')
      var $nextIndicator = $(this.$indicators.children()[this.getItemIndex($next)])
      $nextIndicator && $nextIndicator.addClass('active')
    }

    var slidEvent = $.Event('slid.bs.carousel', { relatedTarget: relatedTarget, direction: direction }) // yes, "slid"
    if ($.support.transition && this.$element.hasClass('slide')) {
      $next.addClass(type)
      $next[0].offsetWidth // force reflow
      $active.addClass(direction)
      $next.addClass(direction)
      $active
        .one('bsTransitionEnd', function () {
          $next.removeClass([type, direction].join(' ')).addClass('active')
          $active.removeClass(['active', direction].join(' '))
          that.sliding = false
          setTimeout(function () {
            that.$element.trigger(slidEvent)
          }, 0)
        })
        .emulateTransitionEnd(Carousel.TRANSITION_DURATION)
    } else {
      $active.removeClass('active')
      $next.addClass('active')
      this.sliding = false
      this.$element.trigger(slidEvent)
    }

    isCycling && this.cycle()

    return this
  }


  // CAROUSEL PLUGIN DEFINITION
  // ==========================

  function Plugin(option) {
    return this.each(function () {
      var $this   = $(this)
      var data    = $this.data('bs.carousel')
      var options = $.extend({}, Carousel.DEFAULTS, $this.data(), typeof option == 'object' && option)
      var action  = typeof option == 'string' ? option : options.slide

      if (!data) $this.data('bs.carousel', (data = new Carousel(this, options)))
      if (typeof option == 'number') data.to(option)
      else if (action) data[action]()
      else if (options.interval) data.pause().cycle()
    })
  }

  var old = $.fn.carousel

  $.fn.carousel             = Plugin
  $.fn.carousel.Constructor = Carousel


  // CAROUSEL NO CONFLICT
  // ====================

  $.fn.carousel.noConflict = function () {
    $.fn.carousel = old
    return this
  }


  // CAROUSEL DATA-API
  // =================

  var clickHandler = function (e) {
    var href
    var $this   = $(this)
    var $target = $($this.attr('data-target') || (href = $this.attr('href')) && href.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]+$)/, '')) // strip for ie7
    if (!$target.hasClass('carousel')) return
    var options = $.extend({}, $target.data(), $this.data())
    var slideIndex = $this.attr('data-slide-to')
    if (slideIndex) options.interval = false

    Plugin.call($target, options)

    if (slideIndex) {
      $target.data('bs.carousel').to(slideIndex)
    }

    e.preventDefault()
  }

  $(document)
    .on('click.bs.carousel.data-api', '[data-slide]', clickHandler)
    .on('click.bs.carousel.data-api', '[data-slide-to]', clickHandler)

  $(window).on('load', function () {
    $('[data-ride="carousel"]').each(function () {
      var $carousel = $(this)
      Plugin.call($carousel, $carousel.data())
    })
  })

}(jQuery);
```

Comment: post the code youve tried?

Comment: I forgot, I just put it up